# Mac mini Server Password Locked

Tags: mac, password, osx-server

I purchased a large inventory of office furniture with IT equipment. The Mac mini server I received is password locked and I can't get in.

When I start the computer I have an option for Admin or Guest User. The Admin account is password locked and the Guest User account wont let me do anything.

How do I access the Admin account without a password?

Answer (score 4):

Since you have no idea what is installed on the Mini, I'd personally reformat and reinstall from scratch rather than using the existing install. Easy to do and lots of information on the process that will come up with a quick search.

Answer (score 1):

Shut down completely, then start the computer in Single User mode by holding command+s after pushing the power button.

When you get a command prompt, type `/sbin/mount -uw /` and press return. Then type `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` and press return. Now type `reboot` and press return. When it reboots, it will go through the Setup Assistant again which will allow you to create a new administrator account.

Comment: Not the best move - you don't want to inherit the old system, as every time something needs updating -  including the OS itself - it will need the original purchaser's password. Nuke & pave is the way to go.